# How to combine chronological events in one row SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my logs table:

| Job_id | Event. | Event_time. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | job_actioned | 1:00 |
| 1001 | job_approved | 1:20 |
| 1001 | job_actioned | 1:45 |
| 1001 | job_approved | 2:22 |
| 1001 | job_actioned | 3:40 |
| 1001 | job_approved | 3:51 |

I would like to match the approval to the previous job so that I can calculate the time it took for each job to be approved like this:

| Job_id | Event. | Event_time. | Event2. | Event_time2. | approve_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | job_actioned | 1:00 | job_approved | 1:20 | 0:20 |
| 1001 | job_actioned | 1:45 | job_approved | 2:22 | 0:37 |
| 1001 | job_actioned | 3:40 | job_approved | 3:51 | 0:11 |

how would I do this on SQL?

I tried LEFT joining each actioned item with each job approved item using a left join then picking the one with the MIN approve time that's greater than 0. This worked but my table has over 1 million rows and I'm not too sure that's the most efficient method.

Comment: which mysql version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

use `rownumber` function and make row number after you can join table and getting your result like this

```
SELECT [t1.Job_id],t1.[EVENT.],t1.[Event_time.],
t2.[EVENT.] as [Event2.],t2.[Event_time.] as [Event_time2.],
DATEDIFF(MINUTE,t1.[Event_time.],t2.[Event_time.]) as [approve_time]
FROM (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Job_id) AS RNO FROM logs
    WHERE [EVENT.] = 'job_approved'
)t1 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Job_id) AS RNO FROM logs
    WHERE [EVENT.] = 'job_actioned'
)t2 ON t1.RNO = t2.RNO
```

Comment: this is tagged mysql not sql server